# R CMD INSTALL on RcppArmadillo source package inhibits installing on other platforms

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package, rcpparmadillo

Running R CMD INSTALL on an RcppArmadillo source package skeleton (`RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()`) on Ubuntu compiles the C++ files and supposedly does nothing else, as checked via Git diffing. However, removing the C++ binaries and copying the exact same package directory to a Windows 10 system and running R CMD INSTALL fails the Windows installation chain (with a generic error). Creating a completely new skeleton on Windows however works as expected.

What does R CMD INSTALL do beyond compiling the source files that makes the source package subsequently unusable for installation on different architectures?

To clarify, I've found a solution in running R CMD build on either platform to generate a tarball and R CMD INSTALL on the specific platform. However, I'm very much interested in the workings of R CMD INSTALL on source packages, as there seem to be changes made that are not directly obvious.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and hi from the RcppArmadillo maintainer.  I do not understand your question.  R operates normally by pairs of `R CMD build .` to install a (source) tarball that you install _separately_ on each architecture via `R CMD INSTALL package_1.2.3.tar.gz` (ie the file created by `R CMD build .`).  What you are attempting is, as I read it, not a documented or recommended method.  Please install from the tarball.

Comment: Thanks, was not aware that building a tarball is the only recommened route.

Comment: As an aside, if you run `./cleanup` after the install step it should also work just fine from the same directory after building once.  But yes _the_ standard procedure is `R CMD build` (i.e. what we all do when we submit to CRAN) followed by `R CMD INSTALL`.

Answer (score 1):

As note in the comment above, the standard way of installing is to run

```
 R CMD build .               # if in the source directory
 R CMD build RcppArmadillo   # if above it
```

and then use the generated file `RcppArmadillo_*.tar.gz` in

```
 R CMD INSTALL RcppArmadillo_*.tar.gz
```

which works on all supported platforms, and always starts from freshly prepared sources.

This approach is general, specified by R itself, and independent of `RcppArmadillo` so there was no bug.